# Inequalities textbook request

Tags: reference-request, inequality

At university I have got a problem set with lots of inequalities. Unfortunately there are no explanations given how to do them. In Highschool we only did very easy inequalities.
Therefore I am looking for a resource for inequalities. Especially for more difficult inequalities like $$1 \leq z \overline {z} \leq 4 ,  |\Im(z)|<\Re (z),$$ where $z$ is a complex number.

I would be glad at any recommendations.

Comment: @Integrator I do not see how these questions are duplicates. One is a reference request, the other is asking about a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to translate this into something you can work with.

So in your example let $z=x+iy$.  Then $\bar{z}=x-iy$.  So you have $$1 \le (x+iy)(x-iy) \le 4 \text{ and } |y|\lt x$$ and you will find $(x+iy)(x-iy)= x^2+y^2$.